# Change TinyMCE HTML after the plugin is enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I can change the HTML displayed in TinyMCE by clicking "restore".  I now wish to return the HTML to the orignal HTML by clicking "cancel".  For the life of me, I cannot figure out why my approach doesn't work (it displays the newly modified HTML).  How is this accomplished.  Please see http://jsfiddle.net/3pn3x4zj/ which is duplicated below.  Thank you.

JavaScript

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#tinymce',
    setup: function (ed) {
        ed.on('init', function (e) {
            e.target.hide();
        });
    }
});

$(function () {

    $('#cancel').hide();

    $('#restore').click(function () {
        console.log('Save old HTML and put new HTML from GET request in DIV');
        $('#cancel').show();
        $('#restore').hide();
        $(this).parent().data('oldHTML', $('#tinymce').html());
        var newHTMLgottenFromGetRequest = '<p>Bar Bar Bar</p>'
        $('#tinymce').html(newHTMLgottenFromGetRequest);
        tinymce.get('tinymce').show();
    });

    $('#cancel').click(function () {
        console.log('Put back original HTML');
        $('#cancel').hide();
        $('#restore').show();
        $('#tinymce').html($(this).parent().data('oldHTML'));
        tinymce.get('tinymce').hide();
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="tinymce">
    <p>Foo Foo Foo</p>
</div>
<button id="restore">restore</button>
<button id="cancel">cancel</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reversing these lines in the `#cancel` click event:

```
$('#tinymce').html($(this).parent().data('oldHTML'));
tinymce.get('tinymce').hide();
```

becomes

```
tinymce.get('tinymce').hide();
$('#tinymce').html($(this).parent().data('oldHTML'));
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy!  See http://jsfiddle.net/3pn3x4zj/4/ for updated script.  Mind letting me know "why" it works?  Thanks

Comment: @user1032531 Not really sure. I'm guessing it has to do with TinyMCE's `get` function but I don't know anymore than that